# html - CSS: How can I vertically align text and form elements in a label tag?

Tags: html, css, tags

I have a `<label>` in my html document, where I have some text and form elements in it.
How can I vertically align them in middle?

```
<label>
    Show
    <select name="list_length" size="1" aria-controls="admin_id">
        <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
    </select>
    entries per page.
</label>

<label>
    Search:
    <input type="text" aria-controls="id_281">
</label>
```

I have added this in the css too:
`display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle`

Answer (score 3):

Set height and line height on the same value:

```
height: 50px;
line-height: 50px;
```

Or try this vertical centering:

http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<label>
    <span>Show</span>
    <select name="list_length" size="1" aria-controls="admin_id">
        <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
    </select>
    <span>entries per page.</span>
</label>

<label>
    <span>Search:</span>
    <input type="text" aria-controls="id_281">
</label>
```

CSS

```
label span,
label input,
label select{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```